# What does `/-/` mean in API?

Tags: api-design

I often see `/-/` in API design, what is it used for?

Is there any related documentation?

I have tried to find it in the following documents, but did not find any relevant information:

- https://cloud.google.com/apis/design
- https://google.aip.dev/general
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: "wildcard"

You cited the explanation.

https://google.aip.dev/159

> AIP-159
> Reading across collections
>
> Sometimes, it is useful for a user to be able to retrieve resources across multiple collections, or retrieve a single resource without needing to know what collection it is in.
>
> Guidance
>
> APIs may support reading resources across multiple collections by allowing users to specify a - (the hyphen or dash character) as a wildcard character in a standard List method:

```
GET /v1/publishers/-/books?filter=...
```